# aurelia-authentication OAuth2 response state value differs

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, aurelia, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm attempting an implementation of aurelia-authentication with an OIDC provider (IdentityServer4) and seem to be running into an issue with logging a user out.

The short of it is I'm not able to logout users successfully using the `authService.logout` function mentioned in the OIDC configuration section (https://aurelia-authentication.spoonx.org/oidc.html).

In looking into it a bit further I've tracked it down to a promise rejection in the logout function which provides the message: "OAuth2 response state value differs"

```
if (logoutResponse.state !== stateValue) {
    return Promise.reject('OAuth2 response state value differs');
}
```

logoutReponse seems to be the culprit as it's coming through as an object with the state property named incorrectly `{/login?state: "qAIxYwKqLHYJtyar2PfdvaROWT1O56P7"}`.

I can actually change the if statement to:

```
if (logoutResponse['/login?state'] !== stateValue) {
    return Promise.reject('OAuth2 response state value differs');
}
```

which seems to be working fine, but requires us to modify the aurelia-authentication source directly.

Any thoughts from anyone as to why the "state" property is coming through as a relative path instead of just "state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending more time on this I was able to track the issue down and find a solution.

The solution was to change the aurelia-authentication authConfig `postLogoutRedirectUri` value to just the root page (http://localhost:8080). Additionally, I needed to define that URI under the `PostLogoutRedirectUris` within my IdentityServer4 Client definition.

logoutResponse was then coming through correctly with a property named `state` property that holds the correct value and permits the redirect successfully.